# When a wound / an injury gets some infections

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

What is usually said when someone notices that their wound / injury has infection?
Which one of the following self-made sentences sound natural to you in this sense:

> - My wound has infected.
> - My wound has an infection.
> - My wound has gotten some infections.

If no one is idiomatic and natural, please let me know what a native speaker would say here?

Comment: I think it should be *"my wound has **been** infected*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wound is infected.

The wound has become infected. The wound has gotten infected.

The wound became infected. The wound got infected.

The wound has been infected for a week.

The wound will get infected. The wound will become infected.